# Is there a reusable router / dispatcher for PHP?

Tags: php, url-routing

I'm using a simple framework that handles requests based on query parameters.

```
http://example.com/index.php?event=listPage
http://example.com/index.php?event=itemView&id=1234
```

I want to put clean urls in front of this so you can access it this way:

```
http://example.com/list
http://example.com/items/1234
```

I know how routes and dispatching works, and I could write it myself. But I would rather take advantage of all the code out there that already solves this problem. Does anyone know of a generic library or class that provides this functionality, but will let me **return whatever I want from a route match**?  Something like this.

```
$Router = new Router();
$Router->addRoute('/items/:id', 'itemView', array( 'eventName' => 'itemView' ));

$Router->resolve( '/items/1234' );
// returns array( 'routeName' => 'itemView',
//                'eventName' => 'itemView,
//                'params' => array( 'id' => '1234' ) )
```

Essentially I would be able to do the dispatching myself based on the values resolved from the path.  I wouldn't mind lifting this out of a framework if it's not too much trouble (and as long as the license permits).  But usually I find the routing/dispatching in frameworks to be just a little too integrated to repurpose like this. And my searches seem to suggest that people are writing this themselves if they're not using frameworks.

A good solution would support the following:

- specify routes with colon notation or regex notation
- parse parameters out of routes and return them somehow
- support fast reverse lookup like so:

  ```
  $Router->get( 'itemView', array( 'id' => '1234' ) );
  // returns 'items/1234'
  ```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can also have a look at the Symfony2 routing component!

Comment: Take a look at [Moor](https://github.com/jeffturcotte/moor) and answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11787176/manage-url-routes-in-own-php-framework) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20179984/custom-url-routing-with-php-and-regex).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[GluePHP](http://gluephp.com/) might be very close to what you want. It provides one simple service: to maps URLs to Classes.

```
require_once('glue.php');

$urls = array(
    '/' => 'index',
    '/(?P<number>\d+)' => 'index'
);

class index {
    function GET($matches) {
        if (array_key_exists('number', $matches)) {
            echo "The magic number is: " . $matches['number'];
        } else {
            echo "You did not enter a number.";
        }
    }
}

glue::stick($urls);
```

Comment: Thanks. This is simple enough, and I might be able to adapt it for what I need. I wish the routing an dispatching were decoupled.