# How to understand PHP's URL parsing/routing?

Tags: php, iis, web, url-routing

I just inherited a website built in PHP. The main page of *www.mysite.com* has a *href* to *www.mysite.com/index/35.html* somewhere in the page. In the site's root directory and its children there is no document 35.html.

The number 35 is actually an id found in a DB which also holds the html contents of the page.

If I load URL: www.mysite.com/index.php?id=35 the same page loads.

How does PHP know how to automatically convert

> /index/35.html

to

> /index.php?id=35

---

**EDIT**
Based on the answers, I have found a .htaccess file containing rewrite instructions that would explain the functionality.

However, IIS doesn't seem to (or is not configured) know how to use this. (probably because this is an Apache feature?)

So this begs the following question: **Is there a way to configure IIS to work with this?**

Comment: That is a function of your webserver. Which server are you using? Apache?

Comment: It seems you are talking about dispatcher. Have a look at this [stackoverflow thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348837/is-there-a-reusable-router-dispatcher-for-php).

Comment: See my answer/comment - there was (is) http://www.isapirewrite.com/ i used it when I worked with ColdFusion on IIS and worked very well with standard apache style rewrite commands.

Comment: Thank you all. @Brian gets it for mentioning ISAPI_rewrite for IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will be done usign URL Rewriting using .htaccess - should be in the webroot.

It may look something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

May have other bits, but what this basically tells apache is to send anything that DOES NOT physically exist to index.php

Comment: I do have something similar in my .htaccess, however it doesn't seem to work for IIS. Is this an Apache feature?

Comment: Yes. there is an IIS rewrite tool (http://www.isapirewrite.com/) (not used for serevral years tho personally) which allowed the same use of re-write rules.

Comment: Thank you @Brian, I'll have a look.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't. There is a [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) rule that rewrites from `/index/foo` to `/index.php?id=foo`, either in a `.htaccess` file somewhere or in the httpd configuration itself.

Comment: Great, it is in the .htaccess, but it doesn't seem to work under IIS, meaning the rewrite leads to a 404. Is this an Apache thing?

Comment: Yes, although there are ISAPI modules that can mimic it.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index/([\d]+)\.html /index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

This is off the top of my head. Any browsers trying to load an address starting with index/ has any number ending in .html will be internally redirected to index.php?id= whatever the number is.

Edit: Just saw that your working on IIS. This probably won't work for you. Sorry.

Comment: I have found such a rewrite in a .htaccess file. However, IIS doesn't seem to take advantage of this. Is this Rewrite an Apache feature? Is there an equivalent for IIS?

Comment: @tzup - Yes there is - see my comment above :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you will be using .htaccess to redirect all requests to index.php. From there You can pass the query string a routing class, which will parse the url and identify the unique ids.
In this case we can say like, your routing class will parse the request /index/35.html to `indexController, indexAction, id=35`. now you can pass this id to the model to get corresponding page contents

NB : Here I a am assuming you are using mvc pattern. Anyway it can be treated in your own way, with the concept remaining the same. Hope this make sence.

Comment: Actually, I'm not, but you were on the right track mentioning .htaccess. And I did not vote you down.