# Manage URL routes in own php framework

Tags: php, url, frameworks, routes

I'm creating a PHP Framework and I have some doubts...

The framework takes the url in this way:
`http:/web.com/site/index`

It takes the first parameter to load controller (`site`) and then loads the specific action (`index`).

If you've installed the framework in a base URL works ok, but if you install it in a subfolder like this:
`http://web.com/mysubfolder/controller/action`

My script parses it as controller = `mysubfolder` and action = `controller`.

If you have more subfolders the results will be worst.

This is my Route code:

```
Class Route
{
    private $_htaccess = TRUE;
    private $_suffix = ".jsp";

    public function params()
    {
        $url='';

        //nombre del directorio actual del script ejecutandose.
        //basename(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']));

        if($this->_htaccess !== FALSE):
            //no está funcionando bien si está en un subdirectorio web, por ej stynat.dyndns.org/subdir/
            // muestra el "subdir" como primer parámetro
            $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
            if(isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) && !empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])):
                $url = str_replace("?" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], '',$url);
            endif;
        else:
            if(isset($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'])):
                $url = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
            endif;
        endif;

        $url = explode('/',preg_replace('/^(\/)/','',$url));
        var_dump($url);

        var_dump($_GET);

    }
}
```

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: why re-inventing the wheel? existing MVC frameworks are not good enough?

Comment: "not reinventing the wheel" would Imply That There would be only 1 MVC Framework on the Internet, we could not get better products.
Sometimes it is necessary.

Comment: @codingbiz Dude, just show some Luv ! Excellent argument by Mr. Luv

Comment: @Stefan Luv I wish you goodluck anyway... for your courage. GITHUB!!! :)

Comment: @codingbiz Reinventing the wheel is good when you want to learn about wheels.

Comment: @StefanLuv reinventing the wheel is wrong, there will never be 1 MVC framework on internet but there will be 100 fighting for which is the best one, sorry for my english, and reinventing the wheel is TOTALLY WRONG, it is as to return back everytimes (TOTALLY WRONG for techonology and innovation at all)

Comment: @Ispuk Luckily you didn't tell these to the developers of Wordpress, otherwise the %17 of internet may not be exist :) (Althouh WP is not a framework i guess your opinions on creating a new CMS might be same)

Comment: @ErdinçÇorbacı maybe i do not catched what you are saying cause of my bad english, but don't know if you are referring to WP as a good product for building for example huge traffic sites, hope not :)

Comment: @Ispuk No my friend , i just think that productive free thoughts shouldn't be prevented. Even the first wheel had found that way. Lets sit and wait what he'll produce. Btw your english is not as bad as mine i guess :)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a base path. The routing script must now where to start when detecting a pattern or route detected.

Pseudo code:

```
 //set the base URI
$base_uri = '/base';
//remove the base URI from the original uri. You can also REGEX or string match against it if you want
$route_uri = str_replace($base_uri,'',$uri);
//perform route matching $route_uri, in your code a simple explode

$url = explode('/',preg_replace('/^(\/)/','',$route_uri));
```

You can use this with or without RewriteBase for your .htaccess so long as they use the same harness - index.php.

Additionally, you can improve your route match procedure using Regular Expressions function like preg_match and preg_match_all. They let you define a pattern to match against and results to an array of matching strings - see http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you are creating your own framework, there is no reason not to reuse robust, well tested and documented [components](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/index.html), like this [Routing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing.html) component.

Just use [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/), which has become the standard for dependency management in PHP, and you'll be fine. Add as many components as you want to your stack.

And here you have a ***must read*** [guide](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/50/create-your-own-framework-on-top-of-the-symfony2-components-part-1) on how to make your own framework.

Comment: This is the correct answer. This routing component powers Drupal 8, Larval, and Silex as well.  It is best of breed.  I wrote my own routing framework 7 years ago and am very glad I will never need to do that again.

Comment: No, this is only one possible answer, as the OP has already built a routing mechanism, and is asking for assistance in a specific use case...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think I know how to fix that.

(Disclaimer: I know that you know most of this but I am going to explain everything for others who may not know some of the gotchas)

### Using PATH_INFO and .htaccess

There is a trick in php where if you go to a path like:

http://web.com/mysubfolder/index.php/controller/action

you will get "/controller/action" in the `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` variable

Now what you need to do is take a .htaccess file (or equivalent) and make it tell your php script the current folder depth.

To do this, put the .htaccess file into the "mysubfolder"

```
mysubfolder
    .htaccess
    index.php
```

.htaccess should contain:

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1
```

(I used the [yii framework manual](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/214/url-hide-index-php/) as reference, I also recommend using the [html5 boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/))

Basically you set it up to redirect everything to index.php at a specific point in the url.

Now if you visit: http://web.com/mysubfolder/index.php/controller/action

Now you can get the right path "/controller/action" from `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`

Except it's not going to have any value if you visit http://web.com/mysubfolder/ because the .htaccess file will ignore the rewrite because the http://web.com/mysubfolder/ path requests the mysubfolder/index.php which actually exists and gets denied thank yo `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`.

### [ifsetor](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/ifsetor) function

For this you can use this super handy function called `ifsetor` (I don't remember where I got it)

```
function ifsetor(&$variable, $default = null) {
    return isset($variable)? $variable: $default;
}
```

What it does is take a reference to a variable that might or might not exist and provide a default if it does not exist without throwing any notices or errors

Now you can use it to take the PATH_INFO variable safely like so

In your index.php

```
function ifsetor(&$variable, $default = null) {
    return isset($variable)? $variable: $default;
}
$path = ifsetor($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'],'/');
var_dump($path);
```

php 5.4 also has this new shorter ternary format which you can use if you don't care about notices (I do)

```
$path = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']?:'/';
```

### Handling the QUERY_STRING

Now tecnically you are not getting a URL, it is merely its [path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator) part and will not contain the query_string, for example when visiting

http://web.com/mysubfolder/index.php/test?param=val

you will only get '/test' in the $path variable, to get the query string use the `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` variable

index.php

```
function ifsetor(&$variable, $default = null) {
    return isset($variable)? $variable: $default;
}
$path = ifsetor($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'],'/');
$fullpath = ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])? $path.'?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']:$path;
var_dump($fullpath);
```

But that might depend on your needs

### $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] vs $_GET

Also keep in mind that the `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` variable is different from the `$_GET` and `$_REQUEST` variables because it keeps duplicate parameters from the query string, for example:

Visiting this page

http://web.com/mysubfolder/controller/action?foo=1&foo=2&foo=3

if going to give you a `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` that looks like

```
?foo=1&foo=2&foo=3
```

While the `$_GET` variable is going to be an array like this:

```
array(
    'foo'=>'3'
);
```

### If you don't have .htaccess

You can try using the SCRIPT_NAME to your advantage

```
list($url) = explode('?',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
list($basepath) = explode('index.php',$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$url = substr($url,strlen($basepath));
```

If you like to blow up stuff like me :)

### Your case

```
Class Route
{
private $_htaccess = TRUE;
private $_suffix = ".jsp";

public function params()
{
    $url='';

    //nombre del directorio actual del script ejecutandose.
    //basename(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']));

    if($this->_htaccess !== FALSE):
        //no está funcionando bien si está en un subdirectorio web, por ej stynat.dyndns.org/subdir/
        // muestra el "subdir" como primer parámetro
        list($url) = explode('?',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        $basepath = dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
        $basepath = ($basepath==='/')? $basepath: $basepath.'/';
        $url = substr($url,strlen($basepath));
    else:
        if(isset($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'])):
            $url = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
            $url = preg_replace('|^/|','',$url);
        endif;
    endif;

    $url = explode('/',$url);
    var_dump($url);

    var_dump($_GET);


}
}
```

I hope this helps

P.S. Sorry for the late reply :(

Answer (score 0):

At some point you will have to check the $_SERVER ['HTTP_HOST'] and a config var defined by the programmer/user wich indicates the subfolder(s) where the app is located, and remove the portion you are not interested in from the rest of the URL.

You can check [this forum post](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/60181/) on the codeigniter formus for some hints.

CodeIgniter uses another different way to route the controller/method internally.
You do the routing by the `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` value. You use the urls like this: `myapp.com/index.php/controller/method` .

To avoid showing index.php on the uri you must rely on an Apache rewrite rule, but even with that I think that the CI one is a nice solution, once you have your index file location, you can avoid all the hassle of parsing the URL.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding what you are after correctly, then one solution may be to carry on doing what you are doing, but also get the path of the main routing script (using realpath() for example).

If the last folder (or folder before that etc) matches the beginning URL item (or another section), you ignore it and go for the next one.

Just my 2 cents :-).

Answer (score 0):

Within the application configuration script place a variable which will be set to the path the application runs at.

An alternative is to dynamically set that path.

Before the part

```
$url = explode('/',preg_replace('/^(\/)/','',$url));
```

strip the location (sub-folder) path out of the `$url` string using the predefined application path.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i implemented loader.php

```
   <?php
/*@author arun ak
auto load controller class and function from url*/
class loader
{
    private $request;
    private $className;
    private $funcName;

    function __construct($folder    = array())
    {   
        $parse_res  = parse_url($this->createUrl());
        if(!empty($folder) && trim($folder['path'],DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR)!='')
         {
            $temp_path  = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,trim($parse_res['path'],DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR));
            $folder_path    = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,trim($folder['path'],DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR));
            $temp_path      = array_diff($temp_path,$folder_path);

                if(empty($temp_path))
                {
                    $temp_path =    '';
                }
         }else
         {
            if(trim($parse_res['path'],DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR)!='')
            {
             $temp_path = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,trim($parse_res['path'],DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR));
            }
                 else
             $temp_path ='';
         }
        if(is_array($temp_path))
        {   
            if(count($temp_path) ==1)
            {
                array_push($temp_path,'index');
            }
            foreach($temp_path as $pathname)
            {   
                $this->request .= $pathname.':';
            }
        }
        else $this->request = 'index'.':'.'index';

    }

 private function createUrl()
 {  
    $pageURL  = (@$_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "https://" : "http://";
    $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    return $pageURL;
 }
 public function autolLoad()
 {
    if($this->request) 
    {   
        $parsedPath = explode(':',rtrim($this->request,':'));
        if(is_file(APPLICATION_PATH.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'controllers'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$parsedPath[0].'_controller'.'.php'))
        {
            include_once(APPLICATION_PATH.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'controllers'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$parsedPath[0].'_controller'.'.php');
            if(class_exists($parsedPath[0].'_controller'))
            {
                $class  = $parsedPath[0].'_controller';
                $obj    = new $class();
                //$config       = new config('localhost','Winkstore','nCdyQyEdqDbBFpay','mawinkcms');
                //$connect  =  connectdb::getinstance();
                //$connect->setConfig($config);
                //$connection_obj = $connect->connect();
                //$db               = $connect->getconnection();//mysql link object
                //$obj->setDb($db);
                $method = $parsedPath[1];
                if(method_exists ($obj ,$parsedPath[1] ))
                {
                    $obj->$method();
                }else die('class method '.$method.' not defined');

            }else die('class '.$parsedPath[0]. ' has not been defined' );

        } else die('controller not found plz define one b4 u proceed'.APPLICATION_PATH.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'controllers'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$parsedPath[0].'.php');

     }else{ die('oops request not set,i know tis is not the correct way to error :)'); }
 }

}
```

Now in my index file

```
//include_once('config.php');
include_once('connectdb.php');
require_once('../../../includes/db_connect.php');
include_once('view.php');
include_once('abstractController.php');
include_once('controller.php');
include_once('loader.php');
$loader = new loader(array('path'=>DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'magsonwink'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'modules'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'admin'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'atom'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR));
$loader->autolLoad();
```

I haven't used the concept of modules.only controller action and view are rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have your `htaccess` correctly?

I guess if you're placing your framework on `subfolder`, then you have to change your `RewriteBase` in `htaccess` file from `/` to `/subfolder/`. it would be something like this:

```
# on root
RewriteBase /

#on subfolder
RewriteBase /subfolder/
```

that's only thing I could wonder of that in your case ...

Answer (score 0):

I don't use OOP, but could show you some snippets of how I do things to dynamically detect if I'm in a subdirectory. Too keep it short and to the point I'll only describe parts of it instead of posting all the code.

So I start out with a `.htaccess` that send every request to redirect.php in which I splice up the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variable. I use regex to decide what parts should be keys and what should be values (I do this by assigning anything beginning with 0-9 as a value, and anything beginning with a-z as key) and build the array `$GET[]`.

I then check the path to redirect.php and compare that to my `$GET` array, to decide where the actual URL begins - or in your case, which key is the controller. Would look something like this for you:

```
$controller = keyname($GET, count(explode('/', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']))));
```

And that's it, I have the first part of the URL. The `keyname()` function looks like this:

```
/*************************************
 *  get key name from array position
 *************************************/
function keyname ($arr, $pos)
{
    $pos--;
    if ( ($pos < 0) || ( $pos >= count($arr) ) )
          return "";  // set this any way you like

    reset($arr);
    for($i = 0;$i < $pos; $i++) next($arr);

    return key($arr);
}
```

To get the links pointing right I use a function called `fixpath()` like this:

```
print '<a href="'.fixpath('/admin/logout').'">link</a>';
```

And this is how that function looks:

```
/*************************************
 *   relative to absolute path
 *************************************/
function fixpath ($path)
{
    $root = dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
    if ($root == "\\" || $root == ".") {
        $root = "";
    }
    $newpath = explode('/', $path);
    $newpath[0] .= $root;
    return implode('/', $newpath);    
}
```

I hope that helps and can give you some inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about "reinventing the wheel is wrong" claims. They don't have to use our wheels. I walked on the same road a while ago and i'm totally grateful what i get... i hope you will too

When it comes to the answer to your specific problem -which if faced too- there is a very easy solution. it's a new line in .htaccess at root folder...

Just add line below to your root .htaccess file ; (if your subfoler is "subfolder" )

```
RewriteRule subfolder/ - [L]
```

This will leave apart this folder from rewriting directives

By using this way you can install as many instances of your framework as you wish. But if you want this to be framework driven then you have to create/change .htaccess within your framework.

Answer (score 0):

Create `/myBaseDirectory/public` directory and put your files there - like `index.php`.
This works because Apache sees this directory like base directory.

Answer (score -1):

basically grab the url string after your first slash, and then explode it into an array (i use '/' as a delimiter).

then carefully array_shift off your elements and store them as variables

```
item 0: controller
item 1: the action / method in that controller
item 2 thru n: the remaining array is your params
```

Comment: im getting controller/action with $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] but the problem is, if i have the framework core inside a subfolder, i got /subfolder/controller/action/.

i need to recognize the subfolder structure first, and later obtain a true controller/action called or i ever got a fake controller action(subfolder/subfolder)

Comment: ya i know, but i'm telling you a better way is to use get to simply get the entire url string, and then do all the manipulation from there to extract the data. also, use .htaccess to direct your requests into a single public directory. then use php to generate the content depending on your controller / view , etc

Comment: This will be worst practice @Kristian. You have identify subfolders also.