# Protecting the Functions file from being accessed by URL

Tags: php

I use `functions.php` to call functions like everyone else, But i noticed that anyone can check the page's content just by writing the page url `www.domain.com/functions.php`
i thought about adding `header();` but that would break the entire `include` for all pages, So how do we protect this page without ruining the including pages?

Comment: Route your code in index

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. If your page is pure PHP and does nothing but define a bunch of functions, then accessing the URL `www.domain.com/functions.php` would simply result in a blank page. Ideally, as @sudhakar said, you should be doing routing to handle all requests, anyway.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20179984/custom-url-routing-with-php-and-regex

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20179984/custom-url-routing-with-php-and-regex might help

Comment: @EdCottrell So, Is it normal if someone can access my `header.php` file? just by typing `www.domain.com/source/header.php`, That won't affect my by anything?

Comment: @CaliburVictorious Again, it's not really clear what you're asking. It might affect you, or it might not. It depends on what's in that file. You should read about how to provide a [mcve] to help us answer your questions better. You also might want to read through http://phptherightway.com. Finally, I'd highly recommend that you read [this book](https://leanpub.com/mlaphp). It's intended for experienced developers, but you're heading down a bad path right now, and it will help you get back on the right path. (I have no affiliation with either of those links.)

Comment: @EdCottrell I'll check them, About my question, I'm talking about if someone typed `www.mydomain.com/source/functions.php` and Accessed `functions.php` file, Is there a way to prevent him from accessing it? I tried to redirect him using `header()` but since `functions.php` is `include`d in many pages, Every page of them would get an Error from `header()` that inside `functions.php`

Comment: @CaliburVictorious I've tried to point you in the right direction. You haven't really provided a lot of information to actually help us answer your question about what will happen if the user accesses that URL. So, the best I can tell you is that this kind of thing is typically handled by (1) using a .htaccess file (or the equivalent, depending on your server) to send all traffic to one page, say, index.php, and (2) using logic in your application to handle all requests from there. Beyond that, this is too broad a question for a reasonable answer in Q-and-A format here.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to figure a way in my application requests, If i couldn't I would try `.htaccess`.

Comment: write in .htaccess file
"Redirect  /error.html   http://www.example.com/functions.php"

Answer (score 0):

if you want to stop direct access to `functions.php` by url just put

`defined('BASEPATH')` OR `exit('No direct script access allowed');` at top of file.